# How do you register an event handler for TrackError in AppCenter SDK for C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, visual-studio-app-center

I register event handlers before calling TrackError but they are never called. Yes, the events transpired because the errors showed up in AppCenter.

```
//On loading app
Crashes.SentErrorReport += (sender, args) => { System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); };
Crashes.FailedToSendErrorReport += (sender, args) => { System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); };

AppCenter.Start("{App secret here}" +
       "android={App secret here}" +
       "ios={App secret here}",
       typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));

//Elsewhere in the app
Crashes.TrackError(exception, comments, attachments);
```

Following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin

Comment: have you tried setting them up *after* you start AppCenter?

Comment: @Jason Yes. Then I picked though the documentation and saw where it said they have to be registered before calling AppCenter.Start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported for handled exceptions aka errors in App Center (the ones reported by developer using `Crashes.trackError` manually).

The events are triggered only for crashes (the unhandled exceptions causing the application to exit). Also those events are called after restart of the crashed process.

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume Perrot. Is this explicitly stated in the documentation? Did I overlook this?

Comment: The doc just mentions it is for "crash logs". We didn't insist on the difference between crash and handled errors so I can look into filing a bug to clarify that difference. Handled errors section was added later into the product at the end of the page as an incremental change.

Answer (score 1):

They are never called because the two events handlers are not in the scope of the Page/Fragment/UIViewController anymore. (Page in Xamarin.Forms, Fragment in Xamarin.Android, UIViewController in Xamarin.iOS)

You would need to reassign the event handlers in the new Page. Perhaps define it in a BasePage/BaseViewModel that all the other Pages inherit from.

Comment: And then call AppCenter.Start each time?  Makes no sense.

Comment: No dude, you just call AppCenter.Start once, but you call this `Crashes.SentErrorReport += (sender, args) => { System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); };`
`Crashes.FailedToSendErrorReport += (sender, args) => { System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); };` each time

Comment: Are you only coding for UWP? Or does it not work for Android and iOS as well?